# Optimized storage of Drools kieBase in Redis

Tags: drools

We are using Drools 7.15 version. We have classified the rules based on Customers (customerId, rule files). We create the kieBase for each customer and store it in Redis (key - customerId, value - kieBase). We use regular compression algorithm as shown below. Since we download the kieBase during the start of the application, the size of the kieBase matters. Is there any other compression technique or procedure that I can follow to bring down the size of the kiebase even further? Please let us know your recommendation. Thanks in advance.

ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
GZIPOutputStream zos = new GZIPOutputStream(bos);
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(zos);

P.S: We have thousands of customers and each customer has 10+ rules on average. So the size of the Redis grows really big.

Comment: How are you serializing the KieBases?  In my case, I'm serializing KieBases with around 80 rules and the final size in disk (without any special compression) is around 1M.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I used java serialization. Currently we have around 10K rules and it takes up to 1GB of Redis memory but after compression, it takes upto 160MB. What serialization you use?

Comment: Oh, your original post says 10+ rules :P.
In my case, I create a `kieBase` and then I serialize it with `org.drools.core.util.DroolsStreamUtils`. You can later use that same class to re-create the `kieBase`. Note that this is not serializing any model or dependencies your `kieBase` may have. When deserializing it, you must be sure you have all the required classes in your classpath.

Comment: Yes. I said thousands of customers, so 1000 multiply by 10 gives me 10K rules right? The DroolsStreamUtils you mentioned in turn uses GZIPOutputStream, which I am using currently. I am looking for an alternative compression technique.